# Using SPEmailEventReceiver to receive email to board discussion sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Can anybody help me, I wan to create class inherts from SPEmailEventReceiver to make board discussion sharepoint to receive emails , but i didn't known what the steps to do that ?

Please, can anyone explaine the steps to create this class and how delpoy it to the board discussion sharepoint?

with best regard

Answer (score 0):

WHat do you want to accomplish with your inherited class? Anything special?

The discussion board should be able to receive emails out of the box, it just has to be enabled.

see more about how to post to a discussion board using email [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA101029101033.aspx#3) (at bottom of page).